# Correcting the "wrong" definition of relativistic electric current density

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, charge, electric-current, inertial-frames

In several standard references (I'm using conventions from David Tong's graduate electrodynamics notes), we take charge density $\rho$ as a primitive and then define the current density $\vec{J}$ by the relation
$$
I = \int_S \vec{J} \cdot d \vec{A}
$$
where $S$ is arbitrary oriented surface (not necessarily a closed one) and $I$ is the total signed charge per unit time passing through $S$. By considering the case where $S$ is a small flat surface normal to one of the coordinate axes, and considering the universe's collection of moving charged particles as having a velocity field $\vec{v}(\vec{x},t)$ in addition to its charge density $\rho(\vec{x},t)$ this implies

$$
\vec{J} = \rho \vec{v}.
$$

As David Tong correctly points out, this can't be the "right" answer in some sense, since this can't be the spatial part of a 4-vector. By analogy with 3-momentum and 4-momentum of a massive particle we can quickly guess the corrected relation

$$
\vec{J} = \rho \gamma \vec{v}
$$

where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}}$. But this doesn't explain what's wrong with the original derivation. One of two things must be true:

1. The definition we started with isn't the right one.
2. There are subtle Galilean assumptions we make in deducing $\vec{j} = \rho \vec{v}$ from the given definition.

I can't tell which is the culprit. On one hand, the definition I start with here readily implies

$$
\frac{d \rho}{dt} = - \nabla \cdot \vec{J}
$$

by considering $S$ a closed surface with enclosed charge $Q$, and we know this conservation law is correct. On the other hand, the derivation of $\vec{J} = \rho \vec{v}$ from the starting definition seems very straightforward without hidden assumptions.

Comment: Surely the right one should be closer to $\vec J \to J^{\mu}=\gamma (\rho c,\rho v)$

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In the context of the question, I'm using $\vec{J}$ to denote the spatial component of the relativistic 4-current density $J^\mu$. My point here is that the naive result $\vec{J} = \rho \vec{v}$ seems to be incorrect, and I'm not sure where the error comes from in deducing that result.

Comment: I agree with you that $J^0 = \gamma \rho c$ and $\vec{J} = \gamma \rho \vec{v}$.

Comment: How are you defining $\rho$?  Is it the charge density in the rest frame, or in a frame where the charges are moving?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Michael. I've answered my original question, and in the process I think I've addressed your clarifying question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving the original question here for posterity, but in posting this question I rubber-duck debugged myself and I have found the root cause of my deep confusion: somehow I got it in my head that the exact expression for the relativistic 4-current is $J^\mu = (\gamma \rho c, \gamma \rho \vec{v})$ where $\rho, \vec{v}$ are both as measured in the same inertial frame that is measuring $J^\mu$ to begin with (some sources take $\rho$ as measured in the rest frame of the charges at $\vec{x}$, which of course changes the final expression). To clarify matters, with those definitions the correct expression is

$$
J^\mu = (\rho c, \rho \vec{v}).
$$

The analogy with single-particle mechanical 4-momentum $p^\mu = (\gamma m c, \gamma m \vec{v})$ is misleading because the invariant mass $m$ is a Lorentz scalar while $\rho$ (under my conventions) is not.

I think the root cause of my confusion is that David Tong's notes say that the result $\vec{J} = \rho \vec{v}$ holds "neglecting relativistic effects." I suspect this is just a mistake on his part, or else he means "the definition of $\rho$ is subtle with relativistic effects matter."

Comment: that's what I suggested